# Python-The correct way to structure the code to communicate with DB

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class called `DBConnection` which holds data about financial instruments like stocks. I have another class called `Stock` which takes `ticker` as an input, for example `Stock('AAPL')`. The `Stock` needs a list of methods built around it, for example `is_valid`, `fetch_price` etc. These methods require a DB connection, which is where the confusion arises.

Now should I pass the database connection to the `Stock` class or should I create a helper class to handle all of these methods mentioned before or are both flawed and I need to structure them completely differently?

Comment: Well, what did you try so far and where exactly did you get stuck? You can't expect to get a general design solution here.

Answer (score -1):

In each project (if you don't use a framwork of persistance), you have to do one connection with database(in one file). These connection should connect all Entities that you have in your project. In your case, I suggest the **Product** entity, wich is a principale one that you should have. It should contain the informations of product like : price, color ... So I advice you to start by learning Uml before coding.